# Bootstrap columns not working when writing in php while loop

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my website but when i am adding php loop to show the products the products are shown at the end of the page instead of showing in the area 'product will show here'.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
<div class="features_items">
<h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
<?php
function fetch($table){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id ,name FROM menshirt");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo 
'<div class="col-sm-4">
<h2>$56</h2>
p> '.$name =$row['name'].'</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-cart">  </i>Add to cart</a>
</div>
</div>';
 }
mysqli_close($conn);}
?>
</div></div>
```

[image: image file]

Comment: It's just function `fetch` definition, where do you call it?

Comment: Why are you making the code that is suppose to display your items into a function? Further more, you aren't even using $table in your function.

Comment: function fetch is called from file index.php. when user clicks on the link

Comment: I was just testing the query that it is working or not so instead of $table which is the name of the table in the database , i wrote the name of the table

Comment: i am writing in function so i don't have to write the code again and again for every page

Answer (score 1):

You only creates a function `fetch` which isn't called. And inside open less `div`s than closed.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
    <div class="features_items">
        <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
        <?php

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id ,name FROM menshirt");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo ' 
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>$56</h2>
                p> '. $row['name'] . '</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-cart">  </i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>
                <!--/div--> <!-- you opened one div, tried to close two -->
            ';
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);}

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the function is called from index.php file my question is how to display col-sm-4 under col-sm-9 as it is showing the features item heading

Comment: Sure, you call the function at the end of page, so .col-sm-4 is shown there. If you need it here, forget on `fetch` function, just try the code above.

Comment: Thank you @panther "Sure, you call the function at the end of page"

Comment: Now i am calling where my function is and it is working